# How to Bind SiteMap Treeview datasource using c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, entity-framework, sitemap

I have SiteMap Datasource control on my page

```
<div id="content_inside">


    <asp:SiteMapDataSource ID="SiteMapDataSource1" runat="server" />
         <asp:TreeView ID="TreeView1" ExpandDepth="2"
         </asp:TreeView>

</div>
```

No I am trying to bind it's tree view using the below code snippet

```
  protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var context = new moviescontext ();

            var movies= context.movie.GetAll(ref context);

            if (!IsPostBack)
            {

                TreeView1.DataSourceID = "SiteMapDataSource1";
               TreeView1.DataSource = movies;
                TreeView1.DataBind();


            }
        }
```

Where 'GetAll' is the function which fetched data from the database

```
public static List<movies> GetAll(this IEnumerable<movie> movie, ref moviescontext ctx)
{
    var movies= ctx.movie

                         .Select(s => new movies
                         {
                             MovieId= s.MovieID,
                             MovieName = s.MovieName,

                         }).ToList();

    return movies;
}
```

when I render, the following error occurred

```
HierarchicalDataBoundControl only accepts data sources that implement IHierarchicalDataSource or IHierarchicalEnumerable.
```

Any suggestion?

Comment: Don't use a Hierarchical control when your data only has a single level

Comment: How about If I write the xml into web.sitemap file programmatically. will that be the better approach?

Answer (score 1):

You need to implement the `IHierarchicalEnumerable` interface.

You can do this as follows:

```
        public class MovieCollection : List<Movie>, IHierarchicalEnumerable
        {

            public IHierarchyData GetHierarchyData(object enumeratedItem)
            {
                return enumeratedItem as IHierarchyData;
            }

            public System.Collections.IEnumerator GetEnumerator()
            {
                throw new NotImplementedException();
            }
        }
```

Then add your existing movies like this:

```
public static List<movies> GetAll(this IEnumerable<movie> movie, ref moviescontext ctx)
{
    var movies= ctx.movie

                         .Select(s => new movies
                         {
                             MovieId= s.MovieID,
                             MovieName = s.MovieName,

                         }).ToList();
            var movieCollection = new MovieCollection();
            movieCollection.AddRange(movies);

    return movieCollection;
}
```

The TreeView is usually used to display nested data though and your current data only contains one level.