# How to create a menu from database dynamically by using Entity framework in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, oracle, linq, entity-framework

I was trying to create a menu dynamically from oracle database .I have two tables one is `MANIMENU` and other is `SUBMENU` and structure is as shown below

```
CREATE TABLE "MNIS"."MANIMENU" 
   (    "MAINMENUID" NUMBER NOT NULL ENABLE, 
    "MANIMENU" VARCHAR2(20 BYTE) NOT NULL ENABLE, 
    "MENUORDER" NUMBER, 
    "ISACTIVE" VARCHAR2(20 BYTE), 
    "CONTENT" VARCHAR2(20 BYTE), 


CONSTRAINT "MANIMENU_PK" PRIMARY KEY ("MAINMENUID")
```

---

```
 CREATE TABLE "MNIS"."SUBMENU" 
   (    "SUBMENUID" NUMBER NOT NULL ENABLE, 
    "SUBMENUS" VARCHAR2(20 BYTE) NOT NULL ENABLE, 
    "SUBCONTENT" VARCHAR2(20 BYTE), 
    "MENUORDER" NUMBER, 
    "PARENTID" NUMBER, 
    "ISACTIVE" VARCHAR2(20 BYTE), 
     CONSTRAINT "SUBMENU_PK" PRIMARY KEY ("SUBMENUID")
  USING INDEX PCTFREE 10 INITRANS 2 MAXTRANS 255 
  STORAGE(INITIAL 81920 NEXT 1048576 MINEXTENTS 1 MAXEXTENTS 2147483645
  PCTINCREASE 0 FREELISTS 1 FREELIST GROUPS 1 BUFFER_POOL DEFAULT)
  TABLESPACE "USERS"  ENABLE, 
     CONSTRAINT "SUBMENU_MANIMENU_FK1" FOREIGN KEY ("PARENTID")
      REFERENCES "MNIS"."MANIMENU" ("MAINMENUID") ENABLE
```

and in code behind i used LINQ as shown below

```
 static MenuEntities me = new MenuEntities();

        var xx = from s in me.MANIMENUs
                 where s.ISACTIVE.ToLower() == "y"
                 select s;
        menuBar.DataSource = xx;
```

But failed with an exception .Here `MenuEntities`  is a context class and `menuBar` is id of menucontrol.Can anybody show me how to get a menu by using EF or a simple sample as an example.Do i need to use `Connect by` clause.My database is `ORACLE`

Comment: What was the exception?

Comment: exception is  hierarchical data bound controls only accepts data sources that implement ihierarchical datasource or iheirarchial ienumerable

Comment: See this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21196356/how-to-bind-sitemap-treeview-datasource-using-c-sharp

Comment: @Taher Rahgooy i am not talking about the exception,is there any good samples available which is using Entityframework to get data from database